# How can i increase the width of a DIV vertically ,towards up ie bottom postition needs to be fixed

Tags: javascript, html

How can i increase the height of a DIV vertically ,towards up ie  bottom postition needs to be fixed.(needs to code in JavaScript and HTML).
Height should increase upwards based on content available

Comment: increase width vertically ? You mean increase height ?

Comment: Umh... `div.style.height = 200px`?

Comment: Width of a div vertically ? do you mean height !?

Comment: make it clear. what you want to do ?

Comment: sorry i mean height and should increase upwards based on content available

Answer (score 0):

Place the below in HTML section :

```
<div id="Main" style="position:absolute;top:10px;height:100px;width:100px">
```

Place the below code in the javascript section:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Main").animate({height:'400px'},4000);
 });
```

the  `4000` is the time in which it should happen (4000= 4 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Place the below in HTML section:

```
<div id="Main" style="height:10px">
```

Place the below code in the javascript section:

```
anim("Main", {marginTop:"-400px", height:"410px"}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the below in HTML section:

```
<div id="Main" style="height:10px">
```

Place the below code in the css section:

```
<style>
#Main {
  -webkit-transition:margin-top, height;
  transition:margin-top, height
}
</style>
```

Place the below code in the javascript section:

```
document.getElementById("Main").style.marginTop = "-400px";
document.getElementById("Main").style.height = "410px";
```

Answer (score 0):

From your request "towards up ie bottom postition needs to be fixed", I believe you want a DIV to grow taller while the base does not move.

The magic is in putting an absolutely positioned div, A, inside a relatively positioned div, B, and locating the position of B at the bottom of A. With the bottom of B set, increasing the height of B causes it to grow taller from that fixed location.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #abc;
        }
        div {
            width: 200px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #A {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #369;
            height: 500px;
        }
        #B {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: #69C;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="A">
        <p>This is A</p>
        <div id="B">
            <p>This is B</p>
        </div><!-- /B -->
    </div><!-- /A -->
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#B').animate({'height': 400}, 3000);
    });
</script>
</html>
```